# jQuery Timeline Slider

Tags: jquery, slider

Is there a nice, clean jQuery based timeline slider that you would reccomend?

I need simple, easy to use slider.

Would it be easy to do this in pure CSS?
Using Overflow?

Comment: Not enough information. Which technology to use would depend on the complexity of what you are trying to accomplish, although I would say that it would probably be too complex for CSS to handle in a cross-browser compatible manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possible libraries you could use.

1. [jQuery Tools - Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/index.html)
2. [jQuery UI - Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/)

Both of them are customizable (and that is a good point) so that you have to script a little bit to reach what you're looking for. Have a look to see if it's what you want. Both have a very well explained documentation so it's easy to learn.

I suggest you use one of these two rather than trying to do this using CSS-only. Their codes are ready-to-use so you don't have to worry about little and boring things, like the *slider algorithm*, *cross-browser support* and so on