# Jquery plugin horizontal slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am in search of Jquery horizontal slider. Which i ed as a time line. The slider should be able to read each and every unit for example slider should read from 0-60 mins.  Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Timeline Slider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514133/jquery-timeline-slider)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the jquery UI Slider?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#default